# JSTL setting variable values

Tags: java, performance, jstl

I'm pretty new to JSTL but I'm really stumped on this why would this return a value:

```
<c:set var="childPage" value="<%= resourceResolver.resolve(properties.get(\"childPage\", "")).adaptTo(Users.class)%>" /></c:set>
```

And this would return null?

```
<c:set var="childPage"><%= resourceResolver.resolve(properties.get("childPage", "")).adaptTo(Users.class) %></c:set>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the first one return the expected value? Double quotes in second parameter after clildPage are not escaped. Isn't it a problem, does it compile though?

Comment: You should look at the documentation of `c:set`, [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_set_tag.htm) for example.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: The documentation does not oppose to what Delmon Young is trying to do.

"Value for JSTL <c:set> tag can be specified in body also."

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/02/jstl-tag-examples-in-jsp-java-j2ee.html#ixzz2QvJ4RlDN

Comment: thanks @SotiriosDelimanolis so any idea why setting the value in the body isn't working for me

Comment: @DelmonYoung I would ask you to try to put the `<%= resourceResolver.resolve(properties.get("childPage", "")).adaptTo(Users.class) %>` part outside the `<c:set>` and check what it prints in the `jsp`

Comment: thanks @SotiriosDelimanolis I am able to return a value when I print it out which is odd why it's not working to me when I try to 
put it in the body of <c:set>

Comment: AHHH mixing scriptlets with JSTL? ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 0):

Why not do this:

```
pageContext.setAttribute("childPage", 
    resourceResolver.resolve(properties.get("childPage", "")).adaptTo(Users.class)
);
```

Then you will have access to `${childPage}` within the page.